# How to come out of recv()/recvfrom() , when some event occurs on another thread?

Tags: c, tcp, udp

How to come out of recv()/recvfrom() , when some event occurs on another thread ?

Example code,

```
while ( anyConditionCheckingHere )
{
  if (recv(...) < 0) // ALREADY waiting for message here after fulfilling conditions
  {
  }
}
```

Now if there is **one more thread running in background & some event occurs in that thread,** then How do I stop waiting for message or how do I come out of that blocking call when that event occurs ?

Comment: I solved it by adding timeout to recv()/recvfrom() in socket options.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options I can think of

- use a non blocking socket and continuously poll the data using the code here [C/C++ sockets and a non-blocking recv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326064/c-c-sockets-and-a-non-blocking-recv)
- use select to wait on several file descriptor, saving the resources required for the polling. For instance look in here http://jhshi.me/2013/11/02/use-select-to-monitor-multiple-file-descriptors/index.html#.XBse6FwzaUk

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. Though I already checked those things, but I will do it again now.

Comment: Use `poll` not `select`. This is 2018 not 1990.

Answer (score 1):

If threads are used, there is no need to worry about blocking on `recv()`. When event occurs on next thread, it will get scheduled by scheduler and event will be handled while first thread will continue to block on `recv()`.

Comment: You haven't understood my problem. That event occurs on another thread & I am waiting for message on main thread. Now, when that event occurs, I want to come out of that waiting status on main thread.