# TCP fragmentation - unread bytes

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

A slight variation on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552855/tcp-fragmentation) SO question.

Say the receiver expects packets to be at most 100 bytes.
Say at time X there are actually 100 bytes available in the buffer, but for reasons the receiver only determines it needs to read 75 of those.

What happens with data *not* read from a socket?

Example:
Using flag `MSG_PEEK` (see [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html)) the receiver determines that there is a full valid reply of 75 bytes in the buffer. The remaining 25 bytes must be the start of a next packet.
The receiver elects to remove only 75 bytes (i.e. `::recv()` without the `MSG_PEEK` flag) from the buffer, leaving 25 bytes unread/unmoved in the buffer.

Comment: `Say the receiver expects packets to be at most 100 bytes.` Wrong assumption. There are no *packets* in TCP; it is a *stream* of bytes. (and: *fragmentation* is unrelated) And : these 25 bytes have not been recieved yet, so the cannot be in the buffer.

Comment: Unread data remains to be read. Simple as that.

Comment: Your use of the word "packet" here is completely different -- has almost nothing to do with -- the Internet packets on which TCP is based.  You're imagining that your sender wrote a 75-byte packet (really a message" or a "record") that your program is trying to read.  But that sender's 75-byte message might have been sent as a 40-byte IP packet followed by a 35-byte IP packet, or it might have been concatenated with preceding or following data, and neither of you would ever know.

Comment: @U. Will the data be moved to the front of the buffer and read on the next thread of execution? Will subsequently received data be appended at the rear of unread data? Or does newly received data overwrite all contents of the buffer, effectively discarding (hitherto unread) data still in the buffer?

Comment: @iwarv I think you are confusing yourself by thinking too hard about this "buffer".  Any buffer you might be talking about is an implementation detail, invisible/transparent to you.  TCP simply guarantees that if the sender writes bytes B0 to Bn, you will receive exactly those same bytes, in order.  Any question you might have about the behavior of your program, you can answer based on this guarantee, without worrying about any "buffer".

Comment: Do you know how a data *steam* works? There are not buffered data to be overwritten unless your program does that. @Steve Summit It's possible that the 75-byte message wasn't even sent to the wires.

Comment: To repeat: those 25 unread bytes remain available for reading next time.  Any new data that comes along will be available *after* those 25 bytes.  So, yes, it's true that "subsequently received data is appended at the rear of unread data".  But remember: TCP is not UDP!  Actual packet boundaries are invisible and irrelevant in a TCP stream; they're just implementation details.

Comment: @Steve Agreed. I think people - like me? - coming from older (serial?) interfaces may not appreciate exactly how this is taken care of for you by the socket.
One could easily fall into the trap of greedily reading "whatever the socket has to offer" and managing some complex code to deal with partial messages yourself when you are basically just re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @iwarv Well said!

Comment: @iwarv You're not re-inventing the wheel. That's actually exactly what you should do. It minimizes the number of system calls required and keeps the socket buffers as empty as possible to improve throughput between the server and the client. Dealing with partial messages is quite trivial and you pretty much have already done it if you know how many bytes you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are actually 100 bytes available in the buffer, but for reasons the receiver only determines it needs to read 75 of those.

I guess *receiver* refers to the application reading from the TCP socket. The remaining 25 bytes simply stay in the socket buffer to be read at some later time. If the socket is closed before that the data is lost.

Using the `MSG_PEEK` flag, the read data isn't removed from the buffer at all, so it still contains all 100 bytes after reading.

From the application level, you receive a continous data stream from a TCP socket. If and how the data was segmented or even fragmented for transport doesn't matter and isn't visible to the application. You can read the data in chunks of any size, regardless of how the source application has written it.

> Say the receiver expects packets to be at most 100 bytes.

If you are trying to refer to TCP's *Maximum Segment Size* (MSS), the minimum *Maximum Transfer Unit* (MTU) for IPv4 is 576 bytes, so the minimum MSS is 536 bytes.

Comment: With "packets" I mean the logical datagrams that the sender would stream to the receiver. At some level, all those streamed bytes have to resemble something, otherwise it is just noise. Mostly the receiver will allocate a buffer large enough to accommodate the largest such datagram, in case it's not broken into fragments.

Comment: TCP PDUs are called *segments* and they're transported encapsulated in IP packets. TCP uses send and receive *windows* as buffers. But still, you don't need to know anything about this if you just use a socket. Whether your 100 bytes are transported in a single segment or in ten segments *doesn't matter* one bit. IP packets that are too large for a certain link layer are broken up into several *fragments* but that is something completely different still.